# Multiple IF statements in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I do this in Excel with Multiple IF statements:-

[image]

The conditions:-
1) If Mfc Date is not null, then Mfc Date
2) If Mfc is null, then Rcv Date
3) If both Mfc & Rcv Dates are null, then Tran Date

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `IF` function has the following structure:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

You can nest further IF's in the `[value_if_true]` and/or `[value_if_false]` arguments.

In your particular case, paste this in E2 and copy-drag down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(C2),IF(ISERROR(B2),D2,B2),C2)
```

Now, this assumes that your dates are sometimes `#NULL!` like your question suggests, but I doubt that this is what you actually mean. Maybe you mean blank? Or some other value? If you do mean blank, then replace `ISERROR` with `ISBLANK` in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd write in for say, HIJ assuming by NULL you mean the value 0 and not empty cell:

```
=IF(C4>0,C4,IF(B4>0,B4,D4))
```

In layman's terms, If C4 is greater than 0, give me C4, if it's not then tell me if B4 is greater than 0, and if it is, give me B4, otherwise, just give me D4).