# Multiple IF Statements Excel 2007

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a vector that has different values in it. In the vector next to it I would like to use multiple =IF(FIND(IF(FIND(),IF(FIND(),..... statements.

Here is an example of my data and how I would like the cells next to it to come out:

```
COMPLAINT          | DESCRIPTION <-- How I would like it to come out
CHF                | CHF
COPD (Nos)         | COPD
Chest, Pain, Acute | CHEST PAIN
CP                 | CHEST PAIN
...                | ...
```

What I have written for this is as follows, which does not work:

```
=IF(FIND("CHF",E3,1),"CHF",IF(FIND("COPD",E3,1),"CHF",0))
```

I need to expand the above to accept at least 5 different arguments.  I tried using this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568623/multiple-if-statements-in-excel?rq=1) but I am not following it right.

**EDIT**

I expect the function to work something like this:

```
IF FIND "CHF"
  THEN "CHF"
ELSE IF FIND "COPD"
  THEN "COPD"
ELSE IF FIND "CP"
  THEN "CHEST PAIN"
...
```

Thank you,

Comment: In what way(s) does it not work?  How does the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: I need to add what I expect to my question I apologize, what I need is if "CHF" is found THEN "CHF" but if "COPD" is found THEN "COPD" but if "CP" is fond THEN "CHEST PAIN",...,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's it's better if you have some sort of 'dictionary' to look up the values.

For example, have a table with the following somewhere:

```
CHF          CHF
COPD         COPD
CP           CHEST PAIN
Chest Pain   CHEST PAIN
```

Let's say those are in the range `G2:H5` and that `CHF` begins in cell `A2`.

The first step is to try match `CHF`, `COPD`, `CP` and `Chest Pain` to the cell `A2`. You can use `SEARCH` for this (`FIND` is equivalent but case sensitive).

```
=SEARCH($G$2:$G$5,A2)
```

This gives you errors and a number in case there's a match. To deal with your 3rd sample case, you can first remove the commas with a `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SEARCH($G$2:$G$5,SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))
```

For `CHF`, you'll get

```
 1,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!
```

Using an `IFERROR()` can make the results a little prettier. You can get the index `1` from that, to get CHF from the second table of the lookup table using a `MATCH`:

```
=MATCH(1,SEARCH($G$2:$G$5,SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")),0)
```

And use `INDEX` to bring back the value of the cell from the lookup table...

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$5,MATCH(1,SEARCH($G$2:$G$5,SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")),0))
```

You can also change the size of your lookup table to accommodate any number of values to lookup. The only downside is that it'll be at the expense of performance, but that's only natural if Excel has more values to check.

Now, because of the `SEARCH` (it takes in multiple values instead of a single one), this formula is an array formula. As such, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll have to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you much for this one. I'm out for now but will try this in the morning and if it works then I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Okay, that's fine with me. I actually forgot to mention that it was an array formula, so I added that bit at the end. ^^;