# If equation with three possible outputs

Tags: excel-2010

I've looked for this solution, but it currently eludes me:-  Cell AG15 is the output message cell. If there is a date in A15, I want it to read "Loaded", If there is a date in cells A15 AND M15, I want it to read "Work in Progress", If there is a date in cells A15, M15 AND N15, I want it to read "Waiting Quote"....I seem to have hit a blind spot - I'm sure it's simple Grrrrr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple IF statements in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568623/multiple-if-statements-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can start with:

```
=IF(A15<>"",IF(M15<>"",IF(N15<>"","Waiting Quote","Work in Progress"),"Loaded"),"")
```

Assuming that those cells are empties or contain valid dates (valid for your task, es. M15 < N15). If you have to check if a data is actually a date, you can use the VBA function `IsDate()`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers, Guys, these worked a treat! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to work the other way back i.e. as long as there is a date in N15 you don't need dates in the other two to get "Awaiting quote"

=IF(N15="",IF(M15=,"",IF(A15="","","Loaded"),"Work In Progress"),"Awaiting Quote")